# Converting answer (number) from previous calculation to words. JAVA

Tags: java

```
Scanner kamote = new Scanner (System.in);
    int year, thousands, hundreds, tens, ones;

    System.out.println ("Enter Year: ");
    year = kamote.nextInt();

    thousands = year / 1000 * 1000;
    System.out.println ("Thousands: " +thousands );

    hundreds = ((year/100)*100) - thousands;
    System.out.println("Hundreds: " +hundreds);

    tens = ((year/10)*10) - thousands - hundreds;
    System.out.println("Tens: " +tens);

    ones = year - thousands - hundreds - tens;
    System.out.println ("Ones: " + ones);  
}
```

Above displays the decimal places from thousands to ones respectively but my instructor ask for more complicated one. We need to convert the numbers (answers, example 1000) into words (One Thousand). He said we need to use switch statement here.

Comment: This sounds like you are asking us to do your homework. What have you tried so far? Have you read up on the switch statement in Java? Do that first. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Comment: Im doing this for hours. And after I posted this, I am still looking and doing trial and error. Im not asking for answer, I just want some help by giving tips or if I missed something that needed here.

Comment: Is it possible to insert an if-else statement inside the switch statement?

Comment: No, you choose either of switch of if/else but you don't typically combine both.

Answer (score -1):

Just an idea:

```
int ones = year%10;
int tens = year;
while(tens/10>0)
{
   tens = tens/10;
}
switch(tens)
{
    case 1:
        switch(ones):
            case 1:
                String tensS = eleven;
                break;
            case 2:
                String tensS = twelve;
                break;
            // Ando so on...
        break;
    case 2:
        String tensS = "twenty " + getOnes(ones);
        break;
    case 3:
        String tensS = "thirty " + getOnes(ones);
        break;
    // and so on
}



public String getOnes(int ones)
{
    switch(ones):
    {
        case 1:
            return "one";
        case 2:
            return "two";
        // and so on
    }
}
```

Yo have to use more switch blocks with thousands and hundreds, and then concatenate the whole string